# How to get a task called by grunt-watch to preserve configuration data?

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

In Grunt, I have defined a `server` task that loads some configuration data and calls `grunt.config.set` to save it. Then, it runs some other tasks, among which `watch`. This task, in turn, calls the `replace` task whenever a `.html` file changes.

Now, my problem is that in the `replace` task, I do not seem to be able to access the configuration data loaded in the `server` task. How do I make sure it can access it?

Comment: see answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930717/how-to-modify-grunt-watch-tasks-based-on-the-file-changed/

Comment: I'd found something like that already. It seems that it will help me fix solve the problem, although I haven't gotten it to work completely yet. Since that answer is outdated (it is now `spawn: false`), I'll post an answer here when I've fixed it. Thanks for the help!